# Should an interface function force input?

Tags: .net, interface, architecture

I have a cart application that isn't making use of interfaces at all. I'm trying to re-implement some of the existing functionality using interfaces. I want to build a cart item retrieval interface so that I can have, at the very least, a standard implementation and a test implementation of the interface.

In the existing application there are parameters that are currently being expected on the call to get a cart item. The parameters are an ID and a bool indicating whether or not to retrieve deleted cart items.

Does it make sense to add these parameters now on the standard item retrieval interface? What are some potential pitfalls and work arounds if I plan that in the future I'll either need to add new methods for cart item retrieval or add new parameters to the existing item retrieval functions?

Answer (score 1):

The potential pitfalls and workarounds depend on what you plan to do with your application. If you wish to extract your types interface for decoupling and improving testability, then I see no issues - if you, at some point in the future, require extending the method's signature, you'll simply refactor the signature and modify the parameters in the interface and types that implement it.
If you need more methods for your interface, you just add them and implement them in the deriving types.

When designing an interface, you should consider the following:

- Whether the types that will implement it will be able to implement all the required functionality
- Whether the interface will be used by some third party to extend your application via plugins - making changes to the interface will cause breaking changes to said parties

Based on your description I do not see any issues in using interfaces.

Hopefully, this helps you out.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Because I am still learning and trying to go the route of never updating only making new classes (for now), what I went with was the following: Interface with expected function not taking any parameters. I left the parameter aggregation to the constructor of the object and I created a factory object whos job it'll be to manage the creation of the various instances of the interface. Then when updates are necessary (not fixes) I'll simply extend the factory class with a new create function and if that function supersedes another I'll obsolete the old one.